# Pi Zero White Screen (SPI)

Tags: pi-zero, lcd

I am attempting to get a Pi Zero W v1.1 to work with a screen connected via SPI, but am currently only getting a white screen no matter what I do. The screen in question is [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B085TC5YMR). So far I have attempted the following:

- a fresh install of Pi OS, both Buellsey and Buster (I should see something here accoring to the amazon Q&A
- enabling the SPI and I2C interface options via raspi-config
- Using images provided by the manufacturer found [here](https://osoyoo.com/2016/05/26/osoyoo-lcd-touch-screen-for-raspberry-pi-installation-guide/). I've tried both the Pi and Ubuntu images
- Installing the driver directly as directed by the manufacturer [here](https://osoyoo.com/2016/09/13/install-raspberry-pi-3-5-touch-screen-driver-for-raspbian-jessie/), starting with a fresh image of Pi OS
- Using the LCD35-show script from the [LDC-Show git](https://github.com/waveshare/LCD-show.git)
- re-seating the ribbon cable on the back of the screen, I can't figure out how to dissemble the screen to check if any other connections are loose.

Some of the other info I've found that may also be helpful. The HDMI connection works fine as long as the screen is not attached, but once it is the HDMI output becomes a black screen.

Running evtest returns:

```
No device specified, trying to scan all of /dev/input/event*
Not running as root, no devices may be available.
Available devices:
/dev/input/event0:  ts_kedei_ts
Select the device event number [0-0]:
```

which makes me suspect it is an issue with the connection and not the drivers, but at this point I'm out of ideas.

Update: I've tested my screen on a Pi 2B, and while it did not exactly work as expected (probably a driver issue), it did work, when I moved the screen and SD card to my Pi zero however, the original issue persisted. I suspect the manufacturer was incorrect when they claimed my screen would work with a pi zero 1.